# Did scientists in UK find a sphere that is of extraterrestrial origin which contains alien biota?

Tags: biology, aliens

Is there an independent verification of the claims made by University of Buckingham researchers?

From http://www.express.co.uk/news/weird/554074/Alien-seed-sent-Earth-aliens-Scientists-baffled:

> Professor Wainwright said the structure is made from the metals titanium and vanadium with a “gooey” biological liquid oozing from its centre.
>
> He said there are several theories as to where it came from, the first being it is a complete microorganism programmed to propagate alien life on Earth.
>
> “It is  a ball about the width of a human hair, which has filamentous life on the outside and a gooey biological material oozing from its centre,” he said.
>
> “We were stunned when X-ray analysis showed that the sphere is made up mainly of titanium, with a trace of vanadium.
>
> “One theory is it was sent to Earth by some unknown civilisation in order to continue seeding the planet with life.

...

> Professor Wainwright and his team found the object in dust and particulate matter collected from the stratosphere.
>
> He sent balloons 27km into the sky to collect debris from space and isolated several particles he claims are proof of life in space.

Comment: Curiously, the  University of Buckingham site [links to the same yellowish page you did](http://www.buckingham.ac.uk/research/bcab/news)

Comment: Although their motivation is irrelevant to the evaluation of their results, it may be notable that apparently the scientists are proponents of panspermia and so may be more prone to suggesting an extraterrestrial origin.

Comment: The research paper about this experiment is found [here](http://journalofcosmology.com/JOC23/MiltPaper34.pdf). The journal doesn't appear to be very reputable.

Comment: @KSmarts That link gives me Error 403 Forbidden.  And I'm accessing it from a university network.

Comment: [Wikipedia article about Prof. Wainwright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_Wainwright).

Comment: @gerrit try http://journalofcosmology.com/JOC23/joc-34_wainwright-3.pdf (titled "Biology Associated With A Titanium Sphere Isolated From The Stratosphere" by Milton Wainwright, Christopher E. Rose, Alexander J. Baker, Raisa Karolla and N. Chandra Wickramasinghe)

Comment: [Somewhat related skeptic blog post on work by Chandra Wickramasinghe](http://www.skepticblog.org/2013/01/23/life-in-meteorites-not-so-fast/), which explores in detail how the "Journal of Cosmology" has published a lot of... questionable research.  With a bonus link to Anthony Watts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **Is there an independent verification of the claims made by University of Buckingham researchers?**

No. Currently. Google Scholar only finds two [citations](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cites=7304778795020622411&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) of this 2013 article. Both are by co-authors of the original article. In fact both citations seem (at least superficially) to be the same article repeated twice with minor variations in title.

The Journal of Cosmology appears in a list of [Potential, possible, or probable predatory scholarly open-access journals](http://scholarlyoa.com/individual-journals/)

The journal does not seem to command universal respect for its standards of peer review:

> University of Minnesota biology professor PZ Myers [wrote]
>
> "It isn't a real science journal at all, but is the ginned-up website of a small group of crank academics obsessed with the idea ... that life originated in outer space and simply rained down on Earth," Myers writes on his science blog. "It doesn't exist in print, consists entirely of a crude and ugly website that looks like it was sucked through a wormhole from the 1990s, and publishes lots of empty noise with no substantial editorial restraint."

- [technewsworld](http://www.technewsworld.com/story/72006.html)
- [pharyngula](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/?s=journal+of+cosmology)